# Would being infected with every kind of cold virus strain at once be a good immunization or dangerous?

Tags: immune-system, vaccination, common-cold

I know colds come from around 200 different kinds of viruses.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_cold

But would it be worth the risk to be purposefully infected with every type of strain that causes colds at once, being immune to all of them after? Or would this likely kill someone?

I don't know if there are other diseases where a vaccine isn't available so one just infects oneself so they can prepare for it and get it over with. I know people get chicken pox on purpose when they are a kid but I read it's less dangerous when one is young.

Also, maybe this would be a way to eradicate the disease if everyone did it? But maybe it would be too risky for certain parts of the population.

Comment: @Chris  Roger's ok, the question still remains though

Comment: @Chris Rogers How do you explain this from wiki?The common cold is a viral infection of the upper respiratory tract. The most commonly implicated virus is a rhinovirus (30–80%), a type of picornavirus with 99 known serotypes.[29][30] Other commonly implicated viruses include human coronavirus (≈ 15%),[31][32] influenza viruses (10–15%),[33] adenoviruses (5%),[33] human respiratory syncytial virus, enteroviruses other than rhinoviruses, human parainfluenza viruses, and metapneumovirus.[34] Frequently more than one virus is present.[35] In total over 200 viral types are associated with colds.[3]

Comment: Please accept my apologies as I am wrong with my first comment. See https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/20839/7951

Comment: @Chris Roger Sure thanks for looking into it.